# Firebase database rule to prevent duplicates

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database that looks like this:

```
app-name
 ᠁
[-]⋯users
     ᠁
     ᠁⋯⋯ -AOSa09sd8QEK
     ᠁       ᠁ 
     ᠁       ᠁⋯⋯ date: 12/06/05
     ᠁       ᠁ 
     ᠁       ᠁⋯⋯ email: foo@gmail.com
     ᠁
     ᠁⋯⋯ -AOSa3xsd489E
            ᠁ 
            ᠁⋯⋯ date: 12/36/05
            ᠁ 
            ᠁⋯⋯ email: bar@gmail.com
```

I want to avoid duplicate emails, so that if I try to push an item `{date: 11/06/10, email: bar@gmail.com`, it must be refused and nothing should happen in the database.

My rules are currenly like this:

```
{
  "rules": {      
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
    }
  }
}
```

How can I implement a rule on the Firebase database that prevents the duplicates under this email constraint?

Comment: @chetanmahajan what code do you think is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a rule that checks uniqueness like this.  The best you can do is use a Cloud Function to trigger on the write, which could then perform a query to see if there are now more than 1 records that share the added data.  That means someone just added a duplicate, and it can then be removed in the same function.